# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value or attribute

Tags: java, web, cookies, character

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEf7z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXRnA.png)

How can I solve this problem,this is my first question in stack overflow.I really hope someone can give me some suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: First please go through this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please do NOT post images, post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0 cookie values are restrictive in allowed characters. It only allows URL-safe characters. This covers among others the alphanumeric characters `(a-z, A-Z and 0-9)` and only a few lexical characters, including `-`, `_`, `.`, `~` and `%`. All other characters are invalid in version 0 cookies.

Your best bet is to URL-encode those characters. This way every character which is not allowed in URLs will be percent-encoded in this form `%xx` which is valid as cookie value.

So, when creating the cookie do:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
// ...
```

And when reading the cookie, do:

```
String value = URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8");
// ...
```

Refer to this link:

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value or attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109318/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-control-character-in-cookie-value-or-attribu)

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding future cookies, your solution is simply to URL-encode or Base64-encode the value before setting it in the cookie, and then URL-decode or Base64-decode it at read.

So, when creating the cookie do:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: thank you very much.